# Encountering "No SETUP file exists" installing PyGame with pip

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I've successfully added python and pip to PATH, so I know that's not the problem, and I just installed Python 3.9 (it went in \Users[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39), and I'm just trying to install PyGame. Here's a copy-paste of my command installing it.

```
C:\Users\[me]>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\[me]\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\[me]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\[me]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-jl0qxjpq'
         cwd: C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kgqv4mbp\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried using "python -m pip", same error.

Comment: you have to install the wheel I think search for that on google

Comment: As this question shows up in 2022 as well, this is another hint to check - if your python version is 3.11 then try to lowering it down to 3.10 as there might not yet be 3.11 compatible pygame version available. Once you downgrade your project SDK to 3.10 you might have this issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the issue has been resolved.
I had to install Wheel with `pip install wheel`, and after that the PyGame installation went perfectly.
Thank you, Matiiss